# Problem Enabling Production Mode

Tags: magento2, cache, bug

I have magento CE 2.2.2
I have a problem when i try to enable production mode.

Store give me this error:

```
Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system.
```

If i run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

I have the sample problem.
But if i try to add it_IT , my default language .

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f it_IT
```

Works! But when i run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

The problem returns to the origin : 
 **Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system.**

Comment: so do you get this error when running setup:upgrade

Comment: Yes. When i enable production mode.

Comment: Can you please check dev/static/sign value in core config data table

Comment: https://ibb.co/2t81spD

Comment: Can you please switch its value to 0 and do a check

Comment: https://ibb.co/SJtpJM7 CSS is corrupted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92992/discussion-between-raj-mohan-r-and-kernelpanic).

Comment: Hello @KernelPanic your site has already in production mode just change it in developer mode and then run deploy static command then again run production mode command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please comment properly in `/home/gyps2440/public_html/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme066/Magento_Cms/layout/default.xml` line no 10

```
<!-- <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link"> -->
```

Disable the module TemplateMonster/SiteMaintenance/ as it is creating issues in removing maintenance flag. Remove the maintenance flag manually.

Run the below code to set the proper file permissions

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + 
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + 
sudo chown -R :<web server group> . 
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

If you are running `setup:upgrade` deploy the content. So you need to deploy separately for the Italian store

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it_IT
```